# LinearLayout com 2 textViews para simular um botão

Tags: android, android-layout

O meu objectivo é ter um `Button` com 2 `TextView`s dentro. Pelo que pesquisei a forma mais fácil é ter um `LinearLayout` e dentro colocar os `TextView`s e colocar a propriedade `android:clickable="true"`.

O problema é que não consigo simular a acção do botão porque obtenho uma excepção. Alguém me pode ajudar?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="#D8D8D8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/daily"
        android:text="@string/daily"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:onClick="OnClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/hora"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="Hora"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

No Java, tenho isto:

```
private void OnClick(View view){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new PickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

A `Exception` que estou a obter é:

```
Process: com.converter.android.dailyhoroscope, PID: 7679
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method OnClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.TextView with id 'dailyHoroscope'                                                                                        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4479)                                                                                        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4443)                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Já coloquei o `android:onClick="OnClick"` dentro da `tag` do `LinearLayout` e continuo a obter a excepção.

Comment: O meu problema é no Java o metodo ser private. Tem de ser public.

Comment: Ou `protected` se preferir.

Comment: Onde voce re-escreveu esse metodo onClick @porthfind? e pode ser mais claro no que esta tentando atingir? talvez uma ilustracao?

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Você pode adicionar o click programaticamente!

Para isso deve adicionar um id ao seu LinearLayout e instanciar em sua classe:

Segue um exemplo:

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/liner_layout_id"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="#D8D8D8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
```

**Java**:

```
 LinearLayout objetoClicavel = ((LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.liner_layout_id));
 objetoClicavel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 DialogFragment newFragment = new PickerFragment();
                 newFragment.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
              }
   });
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Saudações!

Comment: Considere usar `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` no LinearLayout. A parte do Java pode ser feita de forma mais simples, criando um objeto pra o LinearLayout e usando um cast tradicional (só para simplificar).